# Move to DIV when toggled with jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll, toggle

I have been reading around, and I am trying to have the screen move to the div that is being toggled. It is at the bottom of my site so when you toggle the contact form, you can't tell it is there unless you scroll down.

I have this snippet of jQuery that doesn't seem to be working

```
//contact toggle
$("#show-con").click(function(){
  $("#contact-wrap").slideToggle("slow");
  $("#contact-wrap").animate({scrollTop: $("#contact-wrap").offset().top});
});
```

The toggle works fine, but it will not scroll to the div.

I read some older articles on here, but unfortunately they linked out to sites no longer active.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will work, use `html, body` for your selector:

```
$("#show-con").click(function(){
  $("#contact-wrap").slideToggle("slow");

  if ($("#contact-wrap").is(':visible')) {
     $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#contact-wrap").offset().top});
  }
});
```

Also added check if element is visible only then scroll not otherwise.

Comment: Is there a way to define this for all elements that have a toggle on them? Or will I have to define each one?

Comment: @ftntravis: You will have to use similar code for them individually or ask another question to get correct sense of your exact requirements since it is a little different question

Answer (score 2):

To define this for all `div`s that have a toggle on them, please refer to http://jsfiddle.net/LkTf8/79/.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".trigger").click(function(e){
  var $toggled = $(this).attr('id');
  var $paneltoggled = $(this).next(".panel").attr('id');

  $(this).next(".panel").slideToggle('slow'); 
  if ($("#" + $paneltoggled).is(':visible')) {
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#" + $paneltoggled).offset().top});}    
  });
});
```